# USB Mouse and Keyboard stop working unexpectedly

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, mouse, laptop, asus

On my laptop I've attached USB mouse and keyboard. They work well when I start the computer. The problem is that after some time they stop working. Laptop's touchpad and keyboard have no problems but the other devices work normally only after **restart** of the laptop. If I unplug USB mouse and keyboard and plug them in again nothing happens. The other USB Devices work properly.

Is there a way to fix this problem permanently or a way to fix it every time when it occurs without restarting?

Comment: There are a few problems in order to reproduce this kind of error one would need the same setup as you. To help solve this problem I suggest first trying the following and posting the results. Type `Ctrl + Alt + T` (to open a terminal) then run `tail -f /var/log/dmesg` See if you get any extra information when the keyboard stops working.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with mouse/keyboard not working so I'll piggyback on this question instead of asking a new one. The differences in my case: I'm using a desktop machine so I'm not constantly unplugging and replugging my mouse and keyboard; I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS; and the problem seems to be limited to within applications: I can move the mouse around, switch applications, even open applications, but I can't do anything in them. This has happened to me twice in just two hours and I'm concerned it is becoming chronic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience, for what it is worth.

I had a similar problem with a Dell e6420 laptop, purchased used with Windows 7, and Ubuntu 14.04 added after the fact by me. The touchpad was turned off, and a Logitech wireless mouse with 'Unifying receiver' used. The primary application is as a Minecraft gaming machine.

After apparently random periods of time these symptoms would appear: the mouse pointer would move, but the mouse buttons and keyboard enter key would stop working. The only consistent work-around I found was a power reset. The quite extensive embedded Dell diagnostics reported no hardware issues.

I noticed that these symptoms primarily occurred with a userid set up with restrictive permissions, and configured to auto-login on boot. Using the "Users and Groups" administrative application (sudo apt-get install gnome-system-tools) I selected the offending account, hit the "Advanced" button, selected the "Permissions" tab and ensured that all check boxes were ticked (In my case, I added ticks to the only three that were not previously selected: tape drives, floppy drives and send and receive faxes. To my mind, the three have no apparent link to mice or keyboards).

With this as the only change, after a reboot the symptoms disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

it's because battery save. it's better to install tlp

http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/tlp-05-released-install-it-in-ubuntu.html

Comment: What bearing does this have on a desktop machine that is always plugged in?